# How to make a complex SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sorting

I am trying to make a similar website to [Hacker News](https://news.ycombinator.com/) and I found this algorithm which needs to help me sort the links on my site, here it is:

```
Score = (P-1) / (T+2)^G

where,
P = points of an item (and -1 is to negate submitters vote)
T = time since submission (in hours)
G = Gravity, defaults to 1.8 in news.arc
```

so I need to make an SQL query which will sort the data using the above equation but I have no idea how to do that. Here is my tables structure:

```
Table 1 name: links
Table 1 fields: id, title, url, user_id, created_at

Table 2 name: votes
Table 2 fields: id, user_id, link_id, vote, created_at
```

in table 2 vote can be one of three values: 1, 0, -1

So is that even possible to do with SQL or do I have to do it in some other way?

Comment: Just nest your equation correctly and use `POWER()` for your ^G

Comment: What `T` supposed to be? Time in days?

Comment: T is the current time minus the time of the creation of a link.

Comment: this is pretty arbitrary to do in sql.  what difficulty are you having in writing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use SQL only method.

First let map every parameter with its candidate in tables:

`P` Sum of **vote** column in `votes` Table.

`T` Current date - `now()` function - minus **created_at** column in `links` Table.

`G` Constant.

With this in mind, the following SQL select statement should return the score for each link.

```
select links.id, (sum(vote) - 1) / POWER(DATEDIFF(now(),links.created_at)*24 + 2, 1.8)
from links, votes
where links.id = votes.link_id
group by links.id
```

`sum(vote)` ==> `P`

`DATEDIFF(now(),links.created_at)*24` ==> `T`.

`1.8` ==> `G`

Comment: This seems to work with minor modifications : )

Comment: I just changed some of it to this: (sum(vote) - 1) / POWER(time_to_sec(TIMEDIFF(now(),links.created_at))/3600, 1.8) as rank    and also added to the end ORDER BY rank DESC

Answer (score 1):

Join the two tables, and use `SUM()` to get the number of votes. I discount the submitter's vote by using `v.user_id != l.user_id` when joining.

You can get `T` using [`SUBTIME()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_subtime).

```
SELECT l.*, IFNULL(SUM(v.vote), 0) AS votes
FROM links AS l
LEFT JOIN votes AS v ON v.link_id = l.id AND v.user_id != l.user_id
GROUP BY l.id
ORDER BY votes / POWER(SUBTIME(NOW(), l.created_at), 1.8)
```

To fix the error, do the grouping in a subquery and ordering in the outer query.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT l.*, IFNULL(SUM(v.vote), 0) AS votes
    FROM links AS l
    LEFT JOIN votes AS v ON v.link_id = l.id AND v.user_id != l.user_id
    GROUP BY l.id
) AS x
ORDER BY votes / POWER(SUBTIME(NOW(), l.created_at), 1.8)
```

Comment: I get the following error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1247 Reference 'votes' not supported (reference to group function)

Comment: I figured that the part that's causing problems is this:  POWER(SUBTIME(NOW(), l.created_at), 1.8)

Comment: I've modified it to do the grouping in a subquery.